# IIS 7.5 access over LAN - SSI (Server Side Includes) problems

Tags: iis-7.5, lan, ssi, windows-firewall

I'm a front end developer, working on IIS/.NET websites. My local development setup is Windows 7 with IIS 7.5. I'm currently working on a mobile site, and want to be able to check it locally on various mobile devices on the LAN.

After a lot of trial and error, I was able to figure out how to access my dev box over the LAN, but I think my solution is a little convoluted... The department standard is to develop under a new IIS "site" for every website we work on (since we work on many different projects and they often have very different requirements), outside of the \inetpub\wwwroot directory. So basically, I don't use the "Default Web Site", but I noticed that that was the only "site" I could access over the LAN. I ended up adding a Virtual Directory on the Default Web Site, pointing to the web root of the site I want to access over the LAN (e.g., "mysite").

I added firewall exceptions for "Secure World Wide Web Services (HTTPS)", "Web Management Service (HTTP)", and "World Wide Web Services (HTTP)", and voila, I can access the site from any device on the LAN, via http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mysite.

The only problem is that the SSIs (Server Side Includes) on the site aren't working. I just get a "Error processing SSI file" message where each file should be included.

I was thinking that it must be a problem with either the way I set up the Virtual Directories, or maybe a security setting that blocks SSI content across the network.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If your html and files aren't in the default Inetpub folder have you added the IUSR_MachineName local account to the NTFS permissions? Otherwise Anonymous authentication won't work.

{Edit}
Sorry I missed the line where you said you changed the firewall permissions and got the sites working. However if the folder the SSI's are in doesn't have the correct NTFS permissions it might mean the Worker Process can't access the includes. (Now I'm guessing)

Comment: Permissions were something that I messed with for a while before getting the site to even work locally. All sites are served out of C:/www, and the permissions I ended up with there included IIS_IUSRS and Users. IUSR is a user in the IIS_IUSRS group, so I'm covered there, right? What other permissions might I need (considering everything works fine locally, just not over LAN)?